# Can i use printf in IO monad?

Tags: haskell

The stopLoss function causes the following error:

```
Could not deduce (Text.Printf.PrintfType (m a0))
arising from the ambiguity check for `stopLoss'
from the context (Monad m,
                Text.Printf.PrintfType (m b),
                Text.Printf.PrintfType (m a))
bound by the inferred type for `stopLoss':
  (Monad m, Text.Printf.PrintfType (m b), 
   Text.Printf.PrintfType (m a)) =>
   Float -> Float -> Float -> m b
Possible fix:
   add an instance declaration for (Text.Printf.PrintfType (m a0))

When checking that `stopLoss'
has the inferred type `forall (m :: * -> *) a b.
  (Monad m, Text.Printf.PrintfType (m b),
   Text.Printf.PrintfType (m a)) =>
   Float -> Float -> Float -> m b'
Probable cause: the inferred type is ambiguous
```

The function:

```
stopLoss qty pb lossRate = do
    let t = qty * pb * (1 + sxf)
    printf "Stop Loss at: %.2f\n" ((pb - (t * lossRate) / qty) :: Float)
    printf "Lost Money: %.2f\n"  ((t * lossRate) :: Float)
```

Any suggestion is appreciated!

Comment: I suggest providing a type signature for `stopLoss`. `printf`’s return type is not limited to `IO ()`, and compiler can’t infer it.

Comment: It is fixed by adding a type signature. thanks!

Comment: As an aside I really recommend `formatting` over `printf`.  It takes many fewer liberties with types.  http://hackage.haskell.org/package/formatting-3.1.0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The type of `printf` is `PrintfType r => String -> r`. The following instances of `PrintfType` are available:

```
IsChar c => PrintfType [c]   
PrintfType (IO a)    
(PrintfArg a, PrintfType r) => PrintfType (a -> r)
```

(The last one is just to make `printf` behave like if it is polyvariadic.)

Here `stopLoss` is a polymorphic function; the type `IO ()` can’t be inferred automatically, and GHC is assuming that the function works for any monad. So, GHC is complaining that the instance of `PrintfType` for a generic monad does not exist.

Providing a type signature like `Float -> Float -> Float -> IO ()` should help.